# How to install a Magento extension when "Update is already in progress"

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm installing new extension in my site. But the problem is that the installation process is stuck on Update in process for more than two hours.

Note that I've installed the same extension yesterday, without any issue on the same server with the same preferences.

This is how I'm looking like now:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does your server error logs tell you anything?

Comment: No error, it give error in cache at the first and it stops, and i click rollback and it goes this way.

Comment: For future comers. Delete the file in **var/.update_in_progress.flag** or run `rm -R  var/.update_in_progress.flag;` While you are at it, there are other files in var/ like `.update_status.txt` which stores the text you are seeing **Update is already in progress.**. So you can also clear that file.

Comment: Solution of Mohammed Joraid did the job for me!! But there is no need to remove the files. Just temporarily add OLD tot the file extension and change it back to the original file extension once installation was succesfull.